# Database Relationship from N t... 1 to N .. N

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

Team can have N users and users can have N teams.
One user can have N answers.
Answer belongs to one user.

[image: UML]

I need help  to build database structure. Important is to get team record from any answer. User can answer only with one team

Comment: Add a TeamUser table containing the foreign keys UserID and TeamID.  Use it to create the many to many relationship described in the first sentence of your question body.

Comment: "User can answer only with one team."  Sounds like you need to add an arrow between Answer and Team.  Otherwise a solution is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Team can have N users and users can have N teams

As Robert Harvey commented, a Membership* table with userId and teamId (foreign keys) will enable the Many to Many relationship.

> Answer belongs to one user.

The Answer table needs to have a userId (foreign key).

> Important is to get team record from any answer. User can answer only with one team

The Answer table also needs teamId (foreign key).

---

*Thanks for the suggestion, JeffO, UserTeams was a stupid name :)

Comment: Or you could call the table Membership.